# Use regex to match file ending with extension war in target folder

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use regex expression to fetch the file from the target folder. I am deploying the war file and for my functional test to run it needs to determine the war file saved in the target folder so that it can install it and run my tomcat instance against it.

I cannot mention static path, as the version of my war will change after release it. I do not want to manually update it every single time.

I used the following regex expression, but that did not seem to work.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(\\.war)$").matcher("./target/");
webapp = new File(matcher.group(1));
```

I am hoping to fetch the war file existing in the target folder.

Also Can I append two different matchers `("./target/" or ./nameOfComponent/target/")` with a single Pattern ?

Comment: Are you asking how to reuse `Pattern.compile("(.+?)(\\.war)$")`? If so just extract a variable

Comment: I was asking how to reuse the Pattern object compiled with ""(.+?)(\\.war)$" for a different path "./modulename/target/", if the file does not exist in the previous path "./parent-target/". So kind of appending to the same Pattern object two path (like Predicate OR in guava), not sure if its even possible. I do not have much knowledge about files and pattern matching in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the files, and check the pattern for each file.

```
// only needed once for all files
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(\\.war)$");

// collect all files in all relevant directories
List<File> potentialFiles = new ArrayList<>();
potentialFiles.addAll(Arrays.asList(new File("./target/").listFiles()));
potentialFiles.addAll(Arrays.asList(new File("./nameOfComponent/target/").listFiles()));

File webapp = null;
for (File file : potentialFiles) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        webapp = file;
        break; // use this line if you only want the first match
    }
}

// use "webapp", but expect null if there was no match
```

Comment: Thanks the solution worked. What a blunder, I was using static string in matcher.

Comment: FYI, I found plugin "maven-dependency-plugin" which would rename the war file and move it to the target folder of my functional test. In that case, I do not have to worry about updating the version in my functional test or using regex to determine the war file being deployed, after I release it, as every single time it will rename it to a particular name mentioned in the plugin "name-of-the-module.war".

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    File dir = new File("directory/path");
    File[] all = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().endsWith(".war");
        }
    });
```

This will get a `File[]` containing all the ".war" files in the "directory/path" folder.